# Simplest PHP File Browser

Tags: php, file-browser

I am looking for a **ultra light PHP filebrowser** which only dispays folders and files.

- Is it easy to program for an ignorant lady like me or is there something I can download?
- Is it possible to use the default filebrowser of firefox? Where is it
  located?

[image]

Thanks XXX!!

Comment: you need a control panel like cPanel where you can view, delete, edit and browse files and folders?

Comment: Well i only need view and brose in a simple way so tthat i can modify it simpli with css

Answer (score 2):

You can use HTML `<input>` [accept](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp) Attribute

```
<input type="file" name="php_file" accept=".php">
```